# Several Access Questions

Tags: ms-access, vba

during my work I accumulated some questions:

1. I have an independent datasheet view form, how can I change its size when it is opened? For example by default it displays 5 columns and 10 rows and the form is just that big.
2. I need to execute several sql clauses, inserts, updates and delete for example. How to use a transaction in Access to bind them together?
3. In some situation I need to decrease a number field in a record. When this number field becomes 0, the record will be deleted or moved in another table. What I'm doing now is firstly using a SELECT clause to take the number field, then minus 1 and test, if it's 0, I do another sql clause to delete the record or move it. Any better way to do this?
4. In the Northwind sample DB provided with Access 2007, the form-head is nice looking, but how it is done? It is a background picture or a theme?

Thanks!

Comment: Please ask the questions individually. Someone might know an answer to one but not all of them, and then it quickly gets hard to keep an overview over what has been answered or not.

Comment: These are good questions, but I would really recommend to split them into four SO questions. This has a lot of advantages: You can provide them with different tags, you can give them a meaningful title (your title right now is not really helpful for people with similar problems), you can mark an answer separately for each question, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You really want to handle the Resize event for the form. Get its current size, and change the number of rows and columns accordingly. Change the Border Style so that the form is resizeable, if you have not already done so.
2. In VBA, you define a transaction on the workspace, viz:

   Set wrkCurrent = DBEngine.Workspaces(0)
   wrkCurrent.BeginTrans
   ...
   wrkCurrent.BeginTrans
3. You could use a VBA RecordSet object instead, if you want to be more efficient.
4. That would be an embedded bitmap. But generally speaking Access is useless when it comes to graphics. Forget the eye candy, and keep your user interface as simple as possible.

Comment: For question 3, but how to use recordset to do deletion? I can change the number fields, but if i do _rst.delete_ to delete the current record, it fails.

Comment: Sorry, but the editor is scrunching up my answer to Q2. Hopefully it is still intelligible. For Q4, use the Image control if you really must.